# Regular expressions in python, find something dependant on count of new lines

Tags: python, regex

I have string in following format:

```
 * some stuff before

Time = 23.96480001

* some stuff that vary - can be 10, can be 100 lines of some stuff

ExecutionTime = 399500.83 s

* some stuff after

Time = 23.96480016

* repeat
```

Where my regex kinda work:

```
rgx = "\nTime = (?P<time>\d+\.\d+)(\n.*){5,810}ExecutionTime = (?P<exec>\d+\.\d+)"
```

But doesn't get everything.

When I get too big or too low number in brackets {,810} it never finds everything.

Is there some way to upgrade this regex not to use x-numbers of new lines but use "until it find ExecutionTime = ... "

Thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to match all following lines that do not start with either `ExecutionTime =` or `Time =` so you do not have to specify a quantifier with a fixed range.

```
^Time = (?P<time>\d+\.\d+)((?:\n(?!(?:Execution)?Time =).*)*)\nExecutionTime = (?P<exec>\d+\.\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Time =`  Match literally
- `(?P<time>\d+\.\d+)` Named group `time` to match 1+ digits, a dot and 1+ digits
- `(` Capture group 1 to capture what is between Time and ExecutionTime

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\n(?!` Match a newline, and assert using a negative lookahead what is to the right is not

      - `(?:Execution)?Time =` Match optional `Execution` and `Time =`
      - `.*` If the assertion is true, match the whole line
    - `)` Close lookahead
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close capture group 1
- `\nExecutionTime =`  Match literally
- `(?P<exec>\d+\.\d+)` Named group `exec` to match 1+ digits, a dot and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AC3aCk/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for help, it works in regex101, but for some reason does not work in my code. I copied bin in regex101 and regex you posted and have zero matches.

Heres copy paste code
https://pastebin.com/5T8k9zVy

Comment: @DavidJakubec You have to add `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` like `l = re.finditer("^Time = (?P<time>\d+\.\d+)((?:\n(?!(?:Execution)?Time =).*)*)\nExecutionTime = (?P<exec>\d+\.\d+)", s, re.M)`